# Qt Quick 3D and Qt Quick Particles (Qt 5.3)

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, particles

I've just started developing a virtual-reality application that uses the Qt Quick 3D library to draw the scene. I am new to Qt Quick, but not new to computer graphics. My scene is extremely basic as of now, but I would like to add small particle effects to it. I have used Qt Quick Particles without Qt 3D, so I understand how to use it, but I could not find any documentation or example code using both Qt Quick Particles and Qt 3D in the same application.

How would I go about this? Thanks in advance.